# Array reshaping without explicitly specifying one dimension

Tags: tensors, list-manipulation

In NumPy a function [numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) can leave at most one dimensional specification unspecified and it will be automatically calculated.

So is there a similar functionality in MMA? As a simplest example I can think of, when I would like to evenly split a `List` with an even-number length, can I not explicitly calculate the length of the two sublists?

```
list = Range[6];
ArrayReshape[#, {2, Length[#]/2}] & [list] (*working*)
Partition[#, Length[#]/2] & [list] (*working*)
ArrayReshape[list, {2, _}] (*not working*)
```

The last line is my naïve attempt and apparently it does not work.

Comment: It's a strange oversight, but I don't think `ArrayReshape` offers this sort of functionality. I'd expect that you could use `Automatic` for one of the dimensions, but that doesn't work.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit It does not have to be `ArrayReshape`, anything as long as an MMA function is OK.

Comment: Via a circuitous route: `Multicolumn[list, 2] // Normal // Transpose`

Comment: A good candidate for the Function Repository...

Comment: Actually, you narrowed question to the 2d case, but `numpy.reshape` with argument -1 works for arbitrary dimensions. It would be interesting to reproduce exactly this with mathematica.

Comment: Hi, @yarchik   you are right, but I just put up an example as simple as I can think of.

Answer (score 9):

`ArrayReshape` doesn't let you do this, but `ReshapeLayer` does:

```
ReshapeLayer[{2, Automatic}] @ Range[6]
ReshapeLayer[{Automatic, 2}] @ Range[6]
```

> {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}}

> {{1., 2.}, {3., 4.}, {5., 6.}}

Unfortunately, `ReshapeLayer` is a neural network function that only works on machine numbers.

Comment: Interesting! But there is a little flaw as you have pointed out.

Comment: It also fails on some machine inputs: `ReshapeLayer[{Automatic, 2}]@
 N[{1, 1, 1, 1.*^39}]`

Answer (score 5):

It's easy enough to compute the missing dimension, which the OP shows, although it would be nice if `Automatic` worked in the way below.

```
list = Range[24];
dims = {2, Automatic, 4};
ArrayReshape[
 list,
 dims /. Automatic ->  (* drops elements that don't fit new dims which *)
   Quotient[Times @@ Dimensions[list],  (* is what ArrayReshape[] does *)
    Times @@ DeleteCases[dims, Automatic]]]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}},
>    {{13, 14, 15, 16}, {17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24}}}
> *)
> ```

General function:

```
ClearAll[arrayReshape];
arrayReshape[
  a_?ArrayQ, 
  dims : {(_Integer | Automatic) ..} /; Count[dims, Automatic] <= 1, 
  p_ : None] := 
 ArrayReshape[
  a, 
  dims /. Automatic -> 
    Quotient[Times @@ Dimensions[a], 
     Times @@ DeleteCases[dims, Automatic]],
  p]
```

Example:

```
ReshapeLayer[{Automatic, 20}]@Range[600] //  Dimensions // RepeatedTiming
arrayReshape[Range[600], {Automatic, 20}] // Dimensions // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> (*
>   {0.0059, {30, 20}}
>   {0.0000119, {30, 20}}
> *)
> ```

One ought to beware that `ReshapeLayer` has considerable overhead and limitations compared to `ArrayReshape`.

Comment: `ReshapeLayer` does indeed have overhead, but the converse is also true. Neural network functions are very fast for large amounts of data and can be very efficiently parallelized on your GPU. If you have lots of large arrays to reshape, I'm pretty sure `ReshapeLayer` will beat `ArrayReshape`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit That's an interesting assertion.  I cannot verify it on my MacBook Pro, but it's probably hardware dependent.  On `Range[600000000]` (4.5GB), `ReshapeLayer` uses 9GB (and 20 sec.), but `ArrayReshape` uses only 4.5GB (and 1.7 sec.).  Copying the array takes almost 4 sec., so if the `ArrayReshape` call necessitates copying the array, it takes longer, 5-6 sec.  But I suspect `ArrayReshape` works in a way such that no advantage from parallelization can be had.

Comment: All neural network layers can handle multiple inputs. They automatically map over lists of arguments in the same way as  `Compile[... RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]`. If you have many arrays you need to reshape, this should give `ReshapeLayer` an advantage over mapping `ArrayReshape`, I think.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I guess I don't understand. This fails: `ReshapeLayer[{Automatic, 2}]@{Range@6, Range@8}`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you're right about that. I'm not quite sure at what stage `ReshapeLayer` infers its input and output dimensions.